# make install error when compiling from source

Tags: make, cmake

When I attempt to install dgraph from source I get the following error messages:

[image: dgraph source install make errors]

I have virtually no experience with C or make and I'm afraid to screw with this. I looked everything that looked like an error and could not find an answer that converged on everything I see here.

Make 4.3, Cmake 3.18.4, and Golang 1.17.2 installed. Makefile is present in current working directory and one directory below in a folder name 'dgraph' as well.

Comment: This is likely an issue in the build file for dgraph. You may be able to find support [on Discuss Dgraph](https://discuss.dgraph.io/c/issues/dgraph/38). Alternatively, I can report that [the Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/dgraph/dgraph/) works without a problem and will save you a bunch of post-installation configuration 

Comment: Your question is written in non-reproducible way. Please provide: a link to sources, Ubuntu version, exact steps which were done.

Comment: `cd dgraph/ && wget https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/releases/download/5.2.1/jemalloc-5.2.1.tar.bz2` ...... Besides that, 'dgraph' is available as a snap package : `sudo snap install dgraph` ............ More options: Please read the README* files.